# Have no idea what I'm doing - can you somehow use the cut() function without losing the data values?

Tags: r, split, cut, radix

I'm very new to R and struggling a lot.

I am using a`davis` dataset which compares reported heights and weights to measured results for UCDavis students.

My tutor has asked us whether taller people self-report similarly to shorter people.

Rather than me just pick an arbitrary cut-off for "short", "average", "tall", I wanted R to do it. I thought the cut() function would be useful but it converts it to a factor, so I "lose" the data values.

I ultimately want to do a t.test to compare the self-reporting but I'm stuck at the initial stages. Any help would be gratefully received. Ideally, I want to stick to Base R, not the tidyverse...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It is better to think of this community like you do for Wikipedia. Users come here with a specific question in mind, looking for a specific answer. Therefore, we require a description of the problem, your own attempt at solving the problem, the errors you are getting and what the expected output is. If those boxes are ticked, some kind volunteer may help you out. I hope you have a good time here!

Answer (score 0):

The key idea is that `cut()` produces a *new* variable.  If you have heights in `heights`, use `gp <- cut(heights)` to work out the corresponding group for each entry.  That way you don't lose anything.